# Spring Batch : How to parse a horked CSV file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

One of the common tasks in Spring Batch it is used for is parsing CSV files, but CSV files come in all form and shapes… and some of them are syntactically incorrect.I am currently try to parse an invalid CSV file: 
My CSV file data.CSV:

```
"1;13/4/1992;16/7/2006"
"2;31/5/1993;1/8/2009"
"3;21/4/1990;27/4/2010"
```

I used this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730974/spring-batch-parsing-a-csv-file-with-quotecharacter/55740897#55740897).
This works for me but I want to use a CSV of my own! any suggestion please?

Comment: show me error and data-1.csv.

Comment: You're returning from inside your loop.  This code will always process the first line and then return.  I assume that's not what you mean to be doing. - you really need to describe the problem you're having if fixing that doesn't solve it.

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate question addressing basic file reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324399/196869

Comment: I updated my code @devdotlog you can see the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment of the answer your linked, you can use a `FlatFileItemReader` instead of the `ListItemReader` and it should work. I used the `ListItemReader` in order to provide a self-contained example you can run (without the need to upload a csv file, etc). The point of the other question was about how to trim the leading/trailing `"` before parsing the lines, and the trick was to use a composite item processor as shown in the example.

You don't need to create a new reader, here is an example of a `FlatFileItemReader` you can use with the same example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<String> itemReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<String>()
            .name("itemReader")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("/absolute/path/to/file"))
            .lineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper())
            .build();
}
```

Hope this helps.